# Memory leak in sslyze

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

if i run the follow code in python2.7 in an endless loop to check the ssl protcol support in a regular interval, the memory is getting bigger and bigger until the program fails.

can anyone please help me :(
this is a very serious problem for me.

```
from sslyze.synchronous_scanner import SynchronousScanner
from sslyze.plugins.openssl_cipher_suites_plugin import Tlsv12ScanCommand, Tlsv11ScanCommand, Tlsv10ScanCommand, Sslv30ScanCommand, Sslv20ScanCommand

sslv20 = { 'version': 'SSLv20', 'command': Sslv20ScanCommand() }
sslv30 = { 'version': 'SSLv30', 'command': Sslv30ScanCommand() }
tlsv10 = { 'version': 'TLSv10', 'command': Tlsv10ScanCommand() }
tlsv11 = { 'version': 'TLSv11', 'command': Tlsv11ScanCommand() }
tlsv12 = { 'version': 'TLSv12', 'command': Tlsv12ScanCommand() }

for protocol in [sslv20, sslv30, tlsv10, tlsv11, tlsv12]:
    scanner = SynchronousScanner(network_timeout=2, network_retries=2)
    scan_result = scanner.run_scan_command(server_info, protocol['command'])
    # ...
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: It's a brand new library, still in beta, landing page says: SSLyze has been tested on the following platforms: Windows 7 (32 and 64 bits), Debian 7 (32 and 64 bits), macOS Sierra. Is your platform one of those? You might want to talk to developers about this.

Comment: sslyze has been around a long time, it's not really beta. But I am having the same problem (and in Python 3).

Comment: For those coming across this thread, the OP posted it on GitHub to the sslyze repo, and there is more info there: https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze/issues/196